# Draw.io -- can we make a new shape library by importing SVG?

Tags: draw.io

I can generate SVG from other tools that already have the shapes that I need.  Is there a way to import that SVG as a Draw.io library?

In other words, can I make a custom shape library in Draw.io by importing a collection of SVG shapes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Drag and drop:

If you are using [drawio for desktop](https://github.com/jgraph/drawio-desktop/releases), you can simply drag and drop the `.svg` file in the workspace.

[image]

### Add to `scratchpad`:

Further, you may also add the image to `scratchpad` from right click context menu for easy access.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In the new/edit library dialog it says "drag images" into the dialog. That includes SVG images.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks  :-)