# DRAW.IO Is it possible to convert .svg metadata to drawio's shape language?

Tags: draw.io

drawio has its shape language, but i cant seem to find any solution in which im getting an imported .svg icons' info to match it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDx79.png)

found other case [How to import/convert SVG to native Draw.io shape?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77378903/how-to-import-convert-svg-to-native-draw-io-shape) but it's not my solution, i need to have svg's info in the same language as in drawio shape lang.